# License a .Net Web Site

Tags: asp.net, licensing

I was wondering what is the preferred method of licensing a web site?

I distribute precomplied versions of my web sites with editable APSX files, the code behind is complied into separate DLL's for each page.

I have thought of implementing some sort of text injection into each page, similar to what Telerik controls do, when using a trial version. This demo text would disappear if using a licensed version.

One way I would think is to have the web site contact a web service to determine the license status but this would be an issue if the web service is down for any reason.

Thanks

Comment: Just a thought, how far would the honor system go?

Comment: Do you have a pirating problem?

Comment: No pirating problem that I am aware of, just seeking an industry standard solution. By honor system I mean anyone downloads the full version and pays for it when they use it. I don't keep track of who downloads and whether they pay. I depend on the honor of the individual downloading my software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's absolutely unacceptable to have your controls rely on an external web service to check the license.  The only thing you're going to get out of that is pissed off customers and maintenance issues for yourself.

I strongly encourage you to go with the honor system, or a very simple licensing key file (that never expires).  You're selling a web site, not video games.  Unless you know for a fact that you are losing significant money because of piracy of your product, do not waste your time.  Remember the first rule of optimization!

Answer (score 0):

you could build some sort of license controlmechanism into your website. therefore you could use the URL of the site (typically you sell your asp.net app for one or two urls to somebody), and e.g. you could also build some hardware-key-references into your license mechanism, so that a copy of your software is not possible to run on a different machine.

but keep in mind, all restrictions you build in will result in more work for your paying clients, and there is always somebody who want to try to use your software without paying it!